# starting tmux from within vim chooses wrong terminal-emulator

Tags: r, vim, tmux, vim-plugin, terminal-emulator

I am using the vim-r-plugin for editing r-files in vim and gvim. Starting gvim, opening an R-file, and invoking \rf will fire up a terminal emulator, a tmux-session in this terminal emulator, and a new r-session in this tmux-session.

Possible choices for the terminal emulator on my system are:

```
% sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
Es gibt 5 Auswahlmöglichkeiten für die Alternative x-terminal-emulator (welche /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator bereitstellen).

  Auswahl      Pfad                 Priorität Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/lxterminal   40        automatischer Modus
  1            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm   20        manueller Modus
  2            /usr/bin/lxterm       30        manueller Modus
  3            /usr/bin/lxterminal   40        manueller Modus
* 4            /usr/bin/uxterm       20        manueller Modus
  5            /usr/bin/xterm        20        manueller Modus

Drücken Sie die Eingabetaste, um die aktuelle Wahl[*] beizubehalten, 
oder geben Sie die Auswahlnummer ein: 
%
```

As you can see, my default terminal is set to *uxterm*.  The vim-r-plugin, however, will fire up a *lxterminal*. It seems as if the vim-r-plugin respects the priority values higher than the manual selection by the users.

How can I tell the vim-r-plugin to use *uxterm* instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to explicitly set tmux’s choice of `$TERM` in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "uxterm"
```

Comment: Isn't this string supposed to be "screen" or "screen-256color" (see the man-page of tmux). Anyway, I tried you idea and got an error messages in the result. I might be wrong, but I don't think the variable 'default-terminal' refers to a term-emulator here but to the way characters are coded and represented in the terminal.

Comment: Setting `default-terminal` does change my `TERM`. Have to stop all tmux instances to take effect. But, you're right that "uxterm" gives an error. I supposed you'd have to do an infocmp and tic to create it, but then it still might not solve your problem.

I do see in the `r-plugin.txt` help that you can set `let vimrplugin_term = "uxterm"`. Have you tried setting that in `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Now I wonder, why I did not find this section of the documentation. I works.